# CSS cascade onto child elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to create a CSS layout where I use a set of classes to determine the colour scheme of elements and their contents.

I've run into a bit of a problem regarding cascading (I think) - this seems like a really elementary problem to me but I just can't figure out a simple way of doing it.

```css
.red-content p {
  color: red;
}

.blue-content p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-content">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Blue</p>
  </div>
  <div class="red-content">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Red</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a Codepen that illustrates the problem I am having: https://codepen.io/tomhayes/pen/OJVqKoo

Basically, the blue text should be blue, and the red text should be red, but the rules are conflicting and making all of the text blue.

I can't use the order of the CSS rules to achieve this because the order of the elements will change, and I am trying to avoid needing to use `>` because the elements will sometimes have to be nested several levels deep.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a bit of specificity to your red class.

```css
.red-content:not(.blue-content) p {
  color: red;
}

.blue-content p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-content">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Blue</p>
  </div>
  <div class="red-content">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Red</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> [§ 4.3. The Negation (Matches-None) Pseudo-class:
> `:not()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation)
>
> The `:not()` pseudo-class allows **useless selectors** to be written.
>
> For instance `:not(*|*)`, which represents no element at all, or
> `div:not(span)`, which is equivalent to `div` but with a higher
> specificity.

Comment: Unfortunately I need this to work both ways around, so I don't think this will work - thanks though!

Comment: It works both ways around, whether you reverse the CSS or the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to specify this for paragraphs only?  If not...

```css
.red-content {
  color: red;
}

.blue-content {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-content">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Blue</p>
  </div>
  <div class="red-content">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Red</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I do have to specify the element that is targeted!

Answer (score 0):

Check the placement of the div's, you were missing one for the blue-content, and it was overriding the red-content.

I have added some indentation to help highlight the structure.

```
<div class="blue-content">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Blue</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="red-content">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Red</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I think that was on purpose, the goal being to nest several of these.

Comment: Yeah that's right, the way they are nested is the whole point of the problem. Thanks anyway!